# Retrieving data from database for update

Tags: php, json, ajax, mysqli, crud

I want to retrieve data from my database for editing by user and I don't know where I'm going wrong...

The codes below are supposed to return the information from the database in json format and insert them into existing textboxes for user edit...

My problem is that, when the update button is clicked, nothing works... there is no response from the browser...

Please help... I'm new to all of this

Code to retrieve data from database (fetch.php):

```
<?php
$connect= mysqli_connect("localhost", "Eben", "Pass1234", "stageupgh");

if (isset($_POST['item_id'])) {
    $output= array();
    $procedure= "
        CREATE PROCEDURE whereItem(IN item_id int(11))
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id= item_id;
        END;
    ";
    if (mysqli_query($connect, "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS whereItem")) {
        if (mysqli_query($connect, $procedure)) {
            $query=  "CALL whereItem(".$_POST['item_id'].")";
            $result= mysqli_query($connect, $query);
            while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $output["itemName"]= $row["name"];
                $output['itemDescription']= $row["description"];
                $output['stock']= $row["in_stock"];
                $output['price']= $row["price"];
            }
            echo json_encode($output);
        }
    }
}
```

?>

itemAction.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
    $output= '';
    $connect= mysqli_connect("localhost", "Eben", "Pass1234", "stageupgh");

    if ($_POST["action"]=="Add") {
        $itemName= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["itemName"]);
        $itemDescription= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["itemDescription"]);
        $stock= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["stock"]);
        $price= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["price"]);

        $procedure= "
            CREATE PROCEDURE insertItem(IN name varchar(100), description varchar(250), in_stock int(11), price decimal(6,2))
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO items(name, description, in_stock, price) VALUES (name, description, in_stock, price);
            END
        ";
        if (mysqli_query($connect, "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insertItem")) {
            if(mysqli_query($connect, $procedure)){
                $query= "CALL insertItem('".$itemName."', '".$itemDescription."','".$stock."','".$price."')";
                mysqli_query($connect, $query);
                echo "Data Inserted";
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['action'])=="Edit") {
        $itemName= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["itemName"]);
        $itemDescription= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["itemDescription"]);
        $stock= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["stock"]);
        $price= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["price"]);

        $procedure= "
            CREATE PROCEDURE updateItem(IN item_id int(11), name varchar(100), description  varchar(250), in_stock int(11), price decimal(6,2))
            BEGIN
                UPDATE items SET name= itemName, description= itemDescription, in_stock= stock, price= price WHERE item_id= item_id;
            END;
        ";
        if (mysqli_query($connect, "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS updateUser")) {
            if (mysqli_query($connect, $procedure)) {
                $query= "CALL updateUser('".$_POST['item_id']."', '".$itemName."', '".$itemDescription."',, '".$stock."', '".$price."')";
                mysqli_query($connect, $query);
                echo "Data Updated";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Main body:

```
<div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                    <label class="sr-only">Item Name:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="itemName" name="itemName" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter the item's." autofocus="true">
                                    <p class="text-danger help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                    <label class="sr-only">Description</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Description" id="itemDescription" name="itemDescription" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter the item's description.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                    <label class="sr-only">In Stock</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="In Stock" id="stock" name="stock" required data-validation-required-message="How many items are available">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                    <label class="sr-only">Price (Gh &#x20b5:)</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Unit Price (Gh &#x20b5:)" id="price" name="price" required data-validation-required-message="How many items are available">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div id="success"></div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" id="item_id">
                                    <button type="button" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="float: right; margin-right: 20px;">Add</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    fetchItems();
    function fetchItems(){
        var action= "select";
        $.ajax({
            url: "itemSelect.php",
            method: "POST",
            data:{action:action},
            success: function(data){
                $('#itemName').val('');
                $('#itemDescription').val('');
                $('#stock').val('');
                $('#price').val('');
                $('#action').val("Add");
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        })
    }
    $('#action').click(function(){
        var itemName= $('#itemName').val();
        var itemDescription= $('#itemDescription').val();
        var stock= $('#stock').val();
        var price= $('#price').val();
        var item_id= $('#itemId').val();
        var action= $('#action').text();

        if (itemName!='' && itemDescription!='' && stock!='' && price!='') {
            $.ajax({
                url: "itemAction.php",
                method: "POST",
                data:{itemName:itemName, itemDescription:itemDescription, stock:stock, price:price, item_id:item_id, action:action},
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    fetchItems();
                }
            });
        }else{
            alert("All fields are required");
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.update', function(){
        var item_id= $(this).attr("#item_id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "fetch.php",
            method: "POST",
            data:{item_id:item_id},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data){
                $action('#action').text("Edit");
                $('#itemId').val(item_id);
                $('#itemName').val(data.itemName);
                $('#itemDescription').val(data.itemDescription);
                $('#stock').val(data.stock);
                $('#price').val(data.price);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried echoing something on if _ELSE_ (if creating procedure fails etc...)? Checking for mysqli_errors?

Comment: php can be a real pain to debug. Missing a comma or semi-colon is enough to get 'nothing' back from a query. You should check your code for those errors. What I see immediately is that from fetch.php you only return a json object when `isset($_POST['item_id'])` is valid. You could try to insert an else clause and return something. If that something is not returned, then it is probable a problem in your php code.

Comment: Yes please... I will try that...

Comment: Is there a way I can talk to someone privately? I really need the help... Urgently

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that you are connecting to the database successfully. Write some code that will connect to the database, query and echo to the screen when you press the submit button. If this works then one debug item can be checked off you list.